# what is the difference between U name1@@GLIBC with U name2 when using nm one file

Tags: c++, nm

What is the difference between `U name1@GLIBC` with `U name2` when using `nm` one file?

Provide more information:

1. in c++
2. nm one file
3. `U` has two types : (a)end with `@@others`  (b)not end with `@@`